# Inner Joins and a Subquery

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Please bear with me. I have already searched through the posts recommended before I started writing this, but nothing seems to be similar to my situation, so here goes.

**The setup**

1. Order Table (orderID, productID, custID)
2. Customer Table (custID, custName, email, contact)
3. Order_Status Table (orderID, orderDate, custID, status)
4. Metadata Table (id, key, value)

**Sample Data**

*Order Table* (in this example, 3 orders were placed for product #234)

```
12, 234, 1
13, 234, 2
14, 234, 3
```

*Customer Table*

```
1, Sarah, sarah@gmail.com, 111-2345
2, Lyn, lyn@yahoo.com, 112-3434
3, John, john@gmail.com, 123-4444
```

*Order Status Table*

```
12, 2021-02-01, 1, paid
13, 2021-02-03, 2, awaiting payment
14, 2021-02-08, 3, pending
```

*Metadata Table*

```
12, payment_method, cash
12, city, SF
12, state, LUN
13, payment_method, deposit
13, city, QC
13, state, NCR
14, payment_method, cc
14, city, QC
14, state, NCR
15, screen, 1024x768
```

*Expected Output* (some values shortened to save space)

```
custID | Name  |      email      | orderID | orderDate  | payment | status | city | state
============================================================================================
1      | Sarah | sarah@gmail.com |    12   | 2021-02-01 | cash    | paid   | SF   | LUN
2      | Lyn   | lyn@yahoo.com   |    13   | 2021-02-03 | bank    | waiting| QC   | NCR
3      | John  | john@gmail.com  |    14   | 2021-02-08 | credit  | pending| QC   | NCR
```

So far, I'm able to fetch the data corresponding to the "payment" column by way of INNER JOINs, and basically I'm able to fetch the necessary data from the Metadata table by way of a subquery. I'm having difficulty in "JOINING" the first JOIN and the subquery result set.

Here's my code for the JOIN:

```
SELECT  customer.custID,
        customer.custName,
        customer.email,
        order.orderID,
        order_status.orderDate,
        metadata.value AS 'payment_method',
        order_status.status        
FROM    ((( customer
INNER JOIN order 
      ON customer.customer_id = order.customer_id )
INNER JOIN order_status 
      ON order_status.order_id = order.order_id)
INNER JOIN metadata
      ON metadata.id = order.order_id 
      AND metadata.key = 'payment_method')
```

Resultset:

```
custID | custName | email           | orderID | orderDate  | payment_method | status
1      | Sarah    | sarah@gmail.com | 12      | 2021-02-01 | cash           | paid
2      | Lyn      | lyn@yahoo.com   | 13      | 2021-02-03 | deposit        | awaiting payment
3      | John     | john@gmail.com  | 14      | 2021-02-08 | credit card    | pending
```

And here's my code for the subquery:

```
SELECT id, key, value FROM metadata 
       WHERE id = 12
       AND key = ANY (
           SELECT key 
           FROM metadata 
           WHERE key = 'payment_method' 
             OR meta_key = 'city'
             OR meta_key = 'state' 
       )
```

The ID is hardcoded in this instance so I could test the code. The resultset is:

```
  id | key            | value
===================================
  12 | city           | SF
  12 | state          | LUN
  12 | payment_method | cash
```

How do I merge the two tables? Your help is highly appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Either join 3 metadata table copies or use conditional aggregation.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do or what your problem is. "Merge" doesn't mean anything in particular. Are you saying the 1st query metadata table is the 2nd query result? Wrong code doesn't communicate what you wish it did. PS A [mre] includes DDL & DML we can cut & paste & run.

Comment: Order is a reserved word in MySQL, so ...

Comment: @philipxy, I meant "merge" in the sense of joining the result of my first attempt using INNER JOIN (first table) and the subquery (second table).

Comment: @Strawberry. Oh, yeah. I forgot about that. It's been a while since I worked on databases. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  a reference to metadata's tables for each metadata you need  and for this you can use table's names alias

```
SELECT  customer.custID,
        customer.custName,
        customer.email,
        o.orderID,
        order_status.orderDate,
        m1.value AS 'payment_method',
        m2.value AS 'city',  
        m3.value AS 'state'     
        order_status.status        
FROM    customer
INNER JOIN `order` o  ON customer.customer_id = o.customer_id 
INNER JOIN order_status ON order_status.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN metadata m1 ON m1.id = o.order_id 
      AND m1.key = 'payment_method'
INNER JOIN metadata m2 ON m2.id = o.order_id 
      AND m2.key = 'city'
INNER JOIN metadata m3 ON m3.id = o.order_id 
      AND m3.key = 'state'
```

and  as suggested  by @strawberry you should not use reserved  word for table name  ("order") ..  if you really need  then  you should backtics (and alias)

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge! This one is exactly what I need.